# GMM and Instruments

Tags: stata, endogeneity, generalized-moments

I am using GMM for my research work. Previously, I have used ivreg command in stata in which we manually specify the instrumental variable for the endogeneous variable. I was just curious and wondering how stata allots instrument variable for  exogeneous variables while conducting gmm?

Comment: It does not need to, exogenous variables "serve as their own instruments".

Answer (score 0):

When employing GMM in Stata, you have a couple of options at your disposal, especially in Stata 18. One popular choice is the `xtabond2` package, but the `gmm` command is also available. The `xtabond2` package might be accessible in previous Stata versions as well.

**1. xtabond2:** This package provides flexibility in specifying endogenous (gmm) and exogenous (iv) variables. Additionally, it allows you to model endogenous variables in levels, differences, or both (System GMM). There is a wealth of documentation and information available on StataList. The package documentation itself is quite intuitive. I highly recommend reading the following resources for a comprehensive understanding:

*Roodman, D. (2009). "How to do xtabond2: An introduction to difference and system GMM in Stata." The Stata Journal, 9(1), 86–136.*

*Roodman, D. (2009). "Practitioners’ corner: A note on the theme of too many instruments." Oxford Bulletin of Economics and Statistics, 71(1), 135–158. DOI: 10.1111/j.1468-0084.2008.00542.x*

**2.gmm:** Although I'm not personally familiar with this command, you would typically set up the moment conditions of your model and specify which instruments will be exogenous, including those based on the lags of the endogenous variables.I haven't found many additional documents on the implementation of this command. In Stata you can use `help gmm`.